# T-SQL PIVOT и UNPIVOT - принципы работы

Tags: sql-server

В переводной книге не очень понятно пишут. Поясните, пожалуйста, на максимально простых примерах с пояснениями работу этих операторов. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: На максимально простых примерах [Pivot](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_pivot.html) и [Unpivot](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_unpivot.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PIVOT` это когда нужно развернуть вертикальные данные из поля таблицы в несколько полей. Обычно это нужно для репортов. Например бывает необходимо разбить данные по месяцам:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XYZ') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #XYZ
GO
SELECT * INTO #XYZ FROM (VALUES
('2015-01-01',10),('2015-02-01',12),('2015-03-01',11),('2015-04-01',13),('2015-05-01',10)
) as x (Period,Sales)
GO
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,Period) as PeriodMonth, Sales FROM #XYZ) up
PIVOT (SUM(Sales) FOR PeriodMonth IN (January, February, March, April, May)) AS pvt;
GO
```

`UNPIVOT` - это обратный процесс, когда данные из многих колонок нужно собрать в один столбец. Обычно это нужно для нормализации данных:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ABC') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ABC
GO
SELECT * INTO #ABC FROM (
VALUES(1,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','K','L')
) as x(id,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10);
GO
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM #ABC ) as a 
UNPIVOT (ColumnValues FOR ColumnNames IN (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10) ) AS Unpvt
GO
```